# Remove devices associated with iCloud account

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, apple-id

I'm trying to remove my MacBook Pro from being associated with my iCloud account however, when I try to remove the account a dialogue prompts me to make sure that I would like to remove it. For some reason, it lists my device several times and doesn't actually delete the account. I would like to remove any association of my Internet Accounts from my iCloud account and remove the numerous of 'Daniel's MacBook Pro' from my iCloud account.

I have attached screenshot of what I'm prompted with showing the number of 'Daniel MacBook Pro' on the dialogue. Is there a way I can manually remove my MacBook Pro from being associated with my account and, in a sense, start afresh.

[image: System Preferences showing a list of 'Daniel's MacBook Pro' for some reason...]

Comment: So if you click "Remove From All" it will keep it activated?

Comment: Yes, it stays on the devices and then when I press it again it adds another 'Daniel's MacBook Pro' to the list.

Comment: I've gotten into a mess like this not that long ago after playing around with the Yosemite beta. It took a call to Apple customer support to de-authorize all devices and clear that out. I don't think there's another way around it either, since the data appears to be corrupt on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

#### Removing an associated device or computer from an Apple ID

To remove a device or computer from your Apple ID:

1. Open iTunes.
2. Sign in to your Apple ID by choosing Store > Sign In from the iTunes menu.
3. Choose Store > View My Account from the iTunes menu.
4. From the Account Information screen, click Manage Devices.
5. Click the Remove button next to the device name you would like to unassociate.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4627